# Excluding results that have a field that is assigned to a non-unique field in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

I am trying to select from a table (`tblRecords`) and exclude rows that have a value that is repeated in a different table (`tblPerson`). As a visual example:

Current tables:

```
 tblRecords:                    tblPerson:
+------------+-------------+   +------------+------------+
| CustomerID | OrderID     |   | PersonID   | UserID     |
+------------+-------------+   +------------+------------+
| 101        |           1 |   | 8          | 3004       |
| 18         |           7 |   | 5          | 81         |
| 8          |           1 |   | 19         | 100        |
| 100        |           2 |   | 19         | 101        |
+------------+-------------+   +------------+------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| CustomerID | OrderID     |
+------------+-------------+
| 18         |           7 |
| 8          |           1 |
+------------+-------------+
```

This is a simplified example, so please forgive signs of bad table design. Since the `PersonID` '19' occurs more than once in `tblPerson`, I want to exclude all results from `tblRecords` where `CustomerID` is the same as a `UserID` that corresponds to a repeated `PersonID` (so exclude 100 and 101).

Instead of grouping by the repeated values, I think the solution would be to use a `NOT EXISTS` in the WHERE clause of my query. Here is the query I wrote that is not working as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM  tblRecords
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM tblPeople
    GROUP BY PersonID
    HAVING COUNT(PersonID) > 1
)
```

I don't understand how to fix the query so it knows to exclude the results from `tblRecords` where the `CustomerID` value appears next to a repeated `PersonID` in `tblPerson`. At the moment, the subquery selects the exact values I want excluded. I just don't know how they logically get searched for in `CustomerID`.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The question is rather non-sensical, because you seem to be talking about one table in the description, but the query refers to two.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I rewrote the question. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @HABO I rewrote the question. Hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the correlation in the `where` clause of the `not exists()` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  ISOW.dbo.tblRecords r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM ISOW.dbo.tblPeople p
    where p.PersonID= r.CustomerID 
    GROUP BY PersonID
    HAVING COUNT(PersonID) > 1
)
```

---

For the updated question, using `not exists()` along with an `exists()`:

```
select r.CustomerID, r.OrderID
from  dbo.tblRecords r
where not exists (
    select PersonID
    from dbo.tblPeople p
    where p.UserID= r.CustomerID 
      and exists (
        select 1
        from dbo.tblPeople i
        where i.PersonID = p.PersonID
          and i.UserID <> p.UserID
      )
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DNWK20907

returns:

```
+------------+---------+
| CustomerID | OrderID |
+------------+---------+
|         18 |       7 |
|          8 |       1 |
+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Congratulation on 30k +1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks! Looks like you aren't too far off either.

Comment: While I changed my question a bit, the WHERE clause you added was what really answered my question. Thanks!